# How can I do a Navigate from another thread?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

Im doing some Httprequest and down the road I want my app to move forward, to another xaml page. Doing this blindly Visual Studio pointed out that I could not do this cross-threddy.

How can I `NavigationService.Navigate()` from another thread?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap it in a `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke` call